# How to force save mp4 files using <a> tag

Tags: html, firefox

The following ref tag does display "Save as" dialog on firefox 33.0. How to force it to display "Save as" dialog instead of playing the video.

```
<a href="/tmp/test.mp4" download="Save">download me</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

This was firefox issue. about:config -> **media.gstreamer.enabled** set to "flase" will trigger download.

Answer (score 0):

Try and change it to:

```
<a href="/tmp/test.mp4" download>download me</a>
```

This worked for me.